# CS50 - Filter segmentation fault - Data structure - c - two dimensional array -

Tags: arrays, c, multidimensional-array, segmentation-fault, cs50

These are the topics that i am facing to implement this program.

Down below I put my code and the apparently solution to my code.
I need some help to understand why the other code is the solution to my problems?

Obviously I don't think it is a good idea to move on without understanding what it is going on in my code.

that why i am here asking for a hand to figure this all out!

.

Details:

`RGBTRIPLE image[height][width]` this is the argument to a function called `grayscale`
.This arguments is a new data type called `RGBTRIPLE`

the output:

getting an image and turning it into a black and white image.
So, we have to calculate the average of the value of  `.rgbtBlue`, `.rgbtGreen` and `.rgbtRed`

This is my code

```
void grayscale(int height, int width, RGBTRIPLE image[height][width])
{
     for (int i = 0; i < height; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < width; j++)
        {
            RGBTRIPLE pixel[i][j];
            int average = round((pixel[i][j].rgbtBlue + pixel[i][j].rgbtGreen + pixel[i][j].rgbtRed) / 3.0);
            
            pixel[i][j].rgbtBlue = average;
            pixel[i][j].rgbtGreen = average;
            pixel[i][j].rgbtRed = average;
        }
    }
    return;
}
```

This is apparently the solution to my problem

[image]

As you can noticed I had the right ideas  or concepts like using a nested loop to access to each element of the 2 dimensional array

```
 for (int i = 0; i < height; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < width; j++)
        {
```

and assigning the average value to every struct

```
            pixel[i][j].rgbtBlue = average;
            pixel[i][j].rgbtGreen = average;
            pixel[i][j].rgbtRed = average;
```

My code actually compiles ok but it gets a `segmentation fault` at the end.
Why do I get a segmentation fault?
I tried to run valgrind to understand the problem and it says that the program is trying to access areas of memory that it isn't supposed to access, but still I don't understand the logic to solve it!
Why is this happening?

There are a few and really important differences between my code and the solution. I have noticed the differences but I don't understand what happens!

can someone explain to me the differences between

```
int average = round((pixel[i][j].rgbtBlue + pixel[i][j].rgbtGreen + pixel[i][j].rgbtRed) / 3.0);`
```

and this

```
 int average = round((pixel.rgbtBlue + pixel.rgbtGreen + pixel.rgbtRed) / 3.0);
```

I did not know it was possible to take the [] away from the data structure.

My thoughts:

I thought that in order to access to one specific element of a 2 dimensional array you needed to use a nested loop and inside of the nested loop you would have to put `pixel[i][j].rgbtBlue`.
I thougth it was required to keep this `[i][j]`  in my code in order to access to the value of each element in a specific location.

I needed to access to each elements of the array (which means the struct) to calculate the  average of `.rgbtBlue`, `.rgbtGreen` and`.rgbtRed` to find the right shade of gray.

another important difference is that i did not put this into my code!

```
RGBTRIPLE pixel = image[i][j]
```

is this what causes my program to get a segmentation fault?
are all my problems caused by this line of code?

It would be a plus if you knew some sort of sources that could me to fill these gap that i have in this particular topic.
Thanks for your help!

Comment: Please show us how you call your function. Is `image` a valid array?

Comment: Please write descriptive titles for your questions. Titles should not be a list of tags. See [How do I write a good title?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10647/how-do-i-write-a-good-title)

Comment: `RGBTRIPLE pixel[i][j];` creates a _new_ arra of size `ixj`. It contains garbage values.

Comment: The solution is simple,but I won't give it because it is homework and you are learning. (Others: please don't give the solution).

Comment: The cause of the seg fault is that there is no `pixel[i][j]`. You can't read it and certainly not assign to it.

Comment: hi @PaulOgilvie - `RGBTRIPLE image[height][width]` this part was given to me. i did not write what 's inside the function or what the functions takes as inputs.  Sorry but i did not really understand your first question!   Image is a Valid array

Comment: Please look carefully at the line _after_ `for (int j = 0; j < width; j++)`. And please look carefully at my comment about `RGBTRIPLE pixel[i][j];`

Comment: did i create a useless array? `RGBTRIPLE pixel[i][j];` . I think i got it. basically, i am not using the input `RGBTRIPLE image[height][width] ` , therefore i am not modifying the image

Comment: @PaulOgilvie what i did was just creating an useless array, right?

Comment: Yes. And you also accessed that array out of bounds. Maximum index is `pixel[i-1][j-1]`. That is what Paul meant when he said "There is no `pixel[i][j]`".

Comment: So is your code working now?

Comment: It is working. Thank you guy for your help and time. @PaulOgilvie